# prove that : $\lim_{x\to \infty} (1+\dfrac{1}{x})^x=e$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that :

$$\lim_n \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n:=e \tag{1}$$

now by using $(1)$ prove that :

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$$

---

$$ \lfloor x\rfloor  \leq x< \lfloor x\rfloor+1$$
for $x \geq 1$ w have :

$$1\leq \lfloor x\rfloor  \leq x\leq \lfloor x\rfloor+1$$

and we deduce :

$$\dfrac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor +1}\leq\dfrac{1}{x}\leq  \dfrac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor }$$

$$1+\dfrac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor +1}\leq1+\dfrac{1}{x}\leq 1+ \dfrac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor }$$

In particular, we deduce that:

$$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor +1}\right)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\leq \left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\leq\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x} \leq\left(1+ \dfrac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor }\right)^x\leq \left(1+ \dfrac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor }\right)^{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}$$

now what ?

Comment: The point is that $f(x)=(1+1/x)^x$ is actually an increasing function on $(0,\infty)$ so that the limit along any sequence of points going to infinity has to be the same.

Comment: @lan . but i want by using $(1)$

Comment: I don't see the distinction between the equation in 1) and the one that immediately follows.

Comment: @DougM Implicitly, $n$ is meant to vary in $\Bbb N$, while x varies in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @DougM. $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Almot1960 You have missed Doug's point. 1. Write down the definition of the limit in both cases. 2. Note that the real case implies the integer. 3. Show that if the function is monotonic the integer case implies the real.

Comment: You have almost completed the proof. Use Squeeze Theorem in last equation and get the desired result. This is one of the ways of getting from the limit using integer variable to the limit using real variable. The technique you have used assumes that there is a theory of irrational exponents without any use of $\log, e, e^{x} $.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps is simpler this way:

Let 
$$f(x)=\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x,\quad x>1$$
$$g(x)=\ln f(x)=x\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)$$
$$g'(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)-\frac 1{x+1}=\int_1^{1+1/x}\frac{dt}t-\frac1{x+1}>\frac1x\cdot\frac1{1+\frac1x}-\frac1{x+1}=0$$

Since $g$ and $\ln$ are increasing, so is $f(x)$.

Then, the existence of the limit of the sequence implies the existence of the limit of the function at $x\to \infty$, and both are equal.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log (1+1/x)^x=x\log (1+1/x)= \frac {\log (1+1/x)-\log (1)}{(1+1/x)-(1)}.$$ As $x\to \infty,$ we have $1/x\to 0,$ so the far RHS of the above line converges to $\frac {d\log y}{dy}|_{y=1},$ which is $\frac {1}{y}|_{y=1}=1.$